# Dynamically Creating HTML Buttons from Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've done some research but I can't find any tutorials or examples. So I thought I would put this out there for someone to answer.

I am trying to create buttons in angular to show up in html. I don't have much code, but here's what I have:

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic'])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($ionicPopup, $scope) {
  }
```

```html
<ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
   <div id="createdBtns" style="margin: 20px">
    <button class="button button-block">Groups</button>
   </div>
   <button id="staticBtn" class="button button-float" ng-click="addContact()">
    <i class="icon ion-plus"></i>
   </button>
  </ion-content>
```

That button won't be there inside the first div. It is just an example of what I want, but created dynamically in angular
I need to create buttons within the HomeCtrl. Can anyone help me out with this?

What I am trying to do:

I will be asking a user for their name. Once I get it, I will create a button on the screen with their name on it. Like this:

```js
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($ionicPopup, $scope) {
 $scope.addContact = function() {
  $ionicPopup.confirm({
   title: 'Import?',
   template: 'Would you like to import a contact from your current contacts?',
   cancelText: 'No',
      okText: 'Yes'
  }).then(function(res) {
   if (res) {
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) {
      alert('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));
    })
```

So then I will create a button with their contact information on it.

Comment: Created dynamically based on what data and criteria? Not at all clear what you are asking

Comment: why do you need to add that dynamically, you can use `ng-hide`, `ng-show`, `ng-if` if you want to conditionally hide/show/render the button in DOM

Comment: The question needs more details, the only idea that comes to my mind, is adding an ng-repeat and an object in the controller side with the name or any other attribute for the button, but what is the purpose of that?

Comment: I just need to be able to create buttons without adding code to html each time. Meaning, when a user creates an object inside the app, it will then create a button with the information they provided. If that is not dynamic i am sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: I added a edit to help explain my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the basic angular functionality. You first have to define some `$scope` data:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($ionicPopup, $scope) {
    // or whatever information your contacts have
    $scope.contacts = [];

    // the code that picks a contact
    //..
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) {
        $scope.contacts.push(contact);
    })

    $scope.doSomethingWithContact = function(contact) {
        console.log(contact);
    }
}
```

Then in your html something like:

```
<button class="button button-block"
        ng-repeat="contact in contacts"
        ng-click="doSomethingWithContact(contact)">
    {{ contact.displayName }} (phone: {{ contact.phoneNumbers[0] }})
</button>
```

Comment: Ok, I did exactly like you did. Because its perfect. But for some reason the button isn't showing up. I don't know whats wrong. Any help?

Comment: Have you verified that the contact actually gets added to the `$scope.contacts`?

Comment: Yes. I console.log($scope.contacts) after pushing contact onto it. and I get, [object Object]

Comment: You might need to trigger an angular digest cycle, because the `navigator` object isn't angular's: `$scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.contacts.push(contact); });`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. Working now!

Answer (score 1):

In the controller's code you would need to create a collection of buttons and assign it to scope. Then in your HTML use `ngRepeat` directive to iterate through that collection and create required buttons. See below code for an example

https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/jASWuwDMX0ojIj3XLZMX/